# Identify polygons within other polygons

Tags: arcgis-desktop, overlapping-features

I have two polygon layers, where one is river catchments and the other is subcatchments.

I want to identify which catchment each subcatchment belongs to. So, I would like either a list where each subcatchment is related to their catchment, or to get the catchment names added to the attribute table for the subcatchment layer.

I have done a lot of searching but have not found anything that answers my questions.

Comment: Try Spatial Join

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple matter of intersecting both layers by using
**Analysis Tools\Overlay\Intersect**

Make sure "*All*" is selected in *JoinAttributes(optional)* input.